# How to make connec localhost to work with new MYSQL version in windows server IIS 7.5

Tags: mysql, wordpress, iis

I have a wordpress websites on windows server IIS 7.5
Now all works with MYSQL 5.6 on port 3306.

I have installed new version of MYSQL 5.7 on port 3307, and the problem that I don't know how to connect my websote to work with the new version 5.7 on port 3307.

To better understood, I need the new ver 5.7 to be default at localhost.
I use Workbenceh and PHPmyadmin and having access to the server since its mine. (virtual server)

Thanks

Comment: Couple of options off the top of my head. **1)** leave code and config alone and change the listen port on the new MySQL to 3306 (then only start one or the other instance of MySQL both will be using 3306) **2)** change the wordpress config to use port 3307

Comment: Option 1 will also mean you dont have 2 instances running using memory at the same time, while you are probably only using the one

Comment: I think it has been well documented https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#set-database-host

Comment: Thanks, of course I use only one MYSQL, where i can find the file wordpress config ?

Comment: Read the document in the comment

Comment: Thanks, all set perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As [Lex Li](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11182/lex-li) mentioned, all these settings located in the wp-confgi.php, the official document has already elaborated on how to configure the database connection. We could migrate the project to use a new database by changing the DB_host settings.
https://wordpress.org/support/article/editing-wp-config-php/#configure-database-settings